# In this.gMap.getUiSettings(),this.gMap.getUiSettings is undefined using Nativescript

Tags: ios, angular, google-maps, nativescript, android-mapview

I'm using [google maps nativescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-google-maps-sdk).

I have this code:

HTML:

```
 <MapView class="map" (mapReady)="onMapReady1($event)" (markerSelect)="onMarkerSelect($event)" height="100%"> </MapView>
```

TS:

```
   public onMapReady1(event) {
        console.log('OnMapReady')
        this.mapView = event.object;
        this.gMap = event.object.gMap;
        var UiSettings = this.gMap.getUiSettings();
        this.gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        UiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Project when I run in Android tns run andorid show correct zoom level and location point and button.

In IOS doesn't show zoom level and location point and button.

Can you ask me any idea how to show in IOS?

Comment: You are accessing the native APIs of Android, which is not valid for iOS. The iOS version of Google Maps SDK doesn't seem to expose such controls.

Comment: Try this If gMap is map object,  this.gMap.setZoom(19)